# How to change default dates values set for hr.holidays form in Odoo 8

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I would like to change the defaults values set for date_from and date_to fields in the hr.holidays form but I can't figure out where those values came from.

There is no _defaults in the model and no defaults= in the fields definition.

Any hint ?

Comment: Can you show the view?

Comment: @gawel just try to show off all the things which u have tried from your hand so that we will figure our what your actual problem is .

Comment: @WoLy the view is https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/addons/hr_holidays/hr_holidays_view.xml#L60 available at /web?debug=#view_type=calendar&model=hr.holidays&menu_id=291&action=385 when you click on a date to create a leave request.

Comment: @DaSaDiYaChaiTAnYa I haven't try anything. I'm trying to find how the default values are set. Since my original post I've seen that those values are injected in the "context" somehow (keys are default_date_to and default_date_from). I've tryed to trace where those data are injected but I'm still lost in the stack.

Comment: @gawel you can check the  state = fields.Selection([
            ('draft', 'Unconfirmed'),
            ('cancel', 'Cancelled'),
            ('open', 'Confirmed'),
            ('done', 'Attended'),
        ], string='Status', default='draft', readonly=True, copy=False)

Comment: @DaSaDiYaChaiTAnYa where ? and how this will help me to find where defaults date values are set/came from ?

Comment: u can  call your function on _default attribute of filed and then check the effect

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured out where those values are set.
It's hardcoded in the web_calendar.js script. See:

https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/addons/web_calendar/static/src/js/web_calendar.js#L627

Answer (score -1):

You can check the sale module check the sale.py for Odoo 9.0 community addons but Odoo 8.0 some module is not yet migrated for new API and do apply your own function make it as your own logic and call it on your field attribute.

**FOR EXAMPLE :**

```
@api.model
def _default_note(self):
    return self.env.user.company_id.sale_note

note = fields.Text('Terms and conditions', default=_default_note)
```

I hope my answer may helpful for you :)

Comment: no, it doesn't help at all. like I said in my answer, the value for those field are set in the js code. thanks anyway

Comment: @gawel you have to write proper question first for only through .js file so this answer is always right but you have to mention that scenario on your question which you have asked please update your question first